# Raspberry pi won't load GUI after running a script

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I have a raspberry pi with raspbian and a 32gb SD card. I need it to run a bash script 24/7, but the script runs for 20-30 minutes and then it stops. And when I reboot the raspberry, it won't load the desktop and this https://i.stack.imgur.com/b165r.jpg shows up. It seems that this is because there isn't enough memory. I guessed it's because of the cache (the script has to open a window in chromium). How can I delete it? Is there a way to do it every time at the end of the script? What else could it be? Thanks.

This is what happens when I do `apt-get purge` anything to free up some space

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5F0FM.jpg

And this is what happens when I write `df -h`... It says that the system is full but how the heck is that possible???

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8uvM.jpg

Comment: This is no developer question, so basically off-topic for SO. Your last screenshot says disk is full. Check whats eating the space

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry where can I post it? I checked and it's because of the cache but I don't know how to clear it and it doesn't show up in `df -h`

Comment: I guess e.g. https://serverfault.com/ is the right one.